# Spring batch jobParameters not working in java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, jobs

I am trying to run a batch job, where I want to make my SQL query dynamic. But I'm getting an exception while building code as **"Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?"**. Below are the code snippets and exception trace for the same.

BatchConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class StoreSalesBatchConfiguration {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("jobBuilderFactory")
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("stepBuilderFactory")
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("jobCompletionNotificationListener")
private JobCompletionNotificationListener jobCompletionNotificationListener;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("jobLauncher")
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("storeSalesJob")
private Job storeSalesJob;

@Autowired
private GameStoreSalesRepository storeSalesRepository;  

@Bean
@StepScope
ItemReader<GameStoreSales> gameStoreSalesReader(@Qualifier("gdwMpsBatch") final DataSource dataSource,
        @Value("#{jobParameters[maxDate]}") String maxDate) {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<GameStoreSales> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    databaseReader.setSql(CommonConstants.STORE_SALES_QUERY);
    databaseReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new PreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            ps.setString(1, maxDate);
        }
    });
    databaseReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(GameStoreSales.class));
    return databaseReader;
}

@Bean
public GameStoreSalesProcessor gameStoreSalesProcessor() {
    return new GameStoreSalesProcessor();
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<GameStoreSales> gameStoreSalesWriter() throws Exception {
    return new GameStoreSalesWriter();
}

@Bean
public Step gameStoreSalesStep(@Qualifier("gdwMpsBatch") final DataSource dataSource,
                            @Value("#{jobParameters[maxDate]}") String maxDate) throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("gameStoreSalesStep").<GameStoreSales, GameStoreSales>chunk(1000)
            .reader(gameStoreSalesReader(dataSource,maxDate)).processor(gameStoreSalesProcessor()).writer(gameStoreSalesWriter()).build();
}

@Bean(name = "storeSalesJob")
public Job storeSalesJob(Step gameStoreSalesStep) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("storeSalesJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(jobCompletionNotificationListener).flow(gameStoreSalesStep).end().build();
}

@Scheduled(cron = "*/30 * * * * *")
public void runStoreSalesJob() throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException,
        JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
    String dateParam = new Date().toString();
    String maxDate = storeSalesRepository.getMaxCalDate();
    JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date", dateParam)
                                                    .addString("maxDate", weekEnd)
                                                    .toJobParameters();
    try{
        jobLauncher.run(storeSalesJob, param);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Exception Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'storeSalesBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storeSalesJob'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storeSalesJob' defined in class path resource [com/staples/mpsbatch/config/StoreSalesBatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'storeSalesJob' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gameStoreSalesStep' defined in class path resource [com/staples/mpsbatch/config/StoreSalesBatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'gameStoreSalesStep' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'storeSalesJob' defined in class path resource [com/staples/mpsbatch/config/StoreSalesBatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'storeSalesJob' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gameStoreSalesStep' defined in class path resource [com/staples/mpsbatch/config/StoreSalesBatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'gameStoreSalesStep' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'gameStoreSalesStep' defined in class path resource [com/staples/mpsbatch/config/StoreSalesBatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'gameStoreSalesStep' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is 

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Please suggest why jobParameters are not being recognised and where the configuration is going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried adding simple quotes around parameters name? Like: `@Value("#{jobParameters['maxDate']}")`

Comment: Yes, I did. But I am getting the same exception yet. It seems it doesn't recognize jobParameters at all.

Comment: The syntax I gave in my previous comment is correct. See here for more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding

Your bean is annotated with `@StepScope`. That's correct.
I don't see any issue with your code. Why the method `gameStoreSalesReader` of your item reader bean is not public? Have you tried to make it public like others?

Comment: @SonamBhardwaj Did you find the root of the problem? or a possible solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

A spring batch **StepScope** object is one which is unique to a specific step and not a singleton. As you probably know, the default bean scope in Spring is a singleton. But by specifying a spring batch component being StepScope means that Spring Batch will use the spring container to instantiate a new instance of that component for each step execution.

This is often useful for doing parameter late binding where a parameter may be specified either at the StepContext or the JobExecutionContext level and needs to be substituted for a placeholder, much like your example with the filename requirement.

Another useful reason to use StepScope is when you decide to reuse the same component in parallel steps. If the component manages any internal state, its important that it be StepScope based so that one thread does not impair the state managed by another thread (e.g, each thread of a given step has its own instance of the StepScope component).

Try annotating with StepScope:

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Step gameStoreSalesStep(@Qualifier("gdwMpsBatch") final DataSource dataSource,
                                @Value("#{jobParameters[maxDate]}") String maxDate) throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("gameStoreSalesStep").<GameStoreSales, GameStoreSales>chunk(1000)
                .reader(gameStoreSalesReader(dataSource,maxDate)).processor(gameStoreSalesProcessor()).writer(gameStoreSalesWriter()).build();
    }
```